# Copy multiple lines from Windows Command prompt without forced newlines

Tags: windows, command-line, copy-paste, newlines

Is it possible to copy multiple lines from the Windows Command Prompt without it inserting a new line where each line reaches the end of the terminal?

For example, if I have the following line in the console:

```
c:\very_long_path_here\more_path_here>command_i_want_to_copy -with -some
arguments that wrap over lines.
```

If I select this and copy it, I will get a newline after the word 'some', which I'll have to delete manually.

Is there a way to copy the data (command that will be parsed, output that is printed) in the form it is interpreted/printed, rather than with hard-wrapped lines?

Comment: In Win 7/8 there is a `clip.exe`, which redirects input to clipboard. You can use it like `c:\> echo your -command | clip.exe`. But it's more suitable for a command output..

Comment: afaik there is no built in way to do this. but maybe you can combine something like a short autoit script with clip.exe to archive your goal

Comment: since windows 10 the default behavior will wrap the line selection so no more problem

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Windows Command Prompt is notoriously broken in this aspect. It is not possible to get the Linux Terminal behavior (at least for pre-Windows 10 according to Luu's comment).

However, there is an obscure feature in cmd.exe which helps: Holding down shift when right clicking into the selected area (to copy) will remove ALL newlines in the copied text.

If you want to select a single long command line (spanning multiple terminal lines) this does what you want. However, it will always remove all newlines, so it is not possible to select multiple command lines (or a script) in a sensible way.

Detailled procedure:

- Select long command line using the left mouse button
- Press down shift
- Right click into the selected area (to copy)
- Release shift
- Now the selected text is in the copy buffer without newlines and you can for example paste it into cmd.exe again using the right mouse button

Comment: Interesting, I'd never heard of that feature. It looks like that's as good as it's going to get. I don't use windows anymore, but when I get the chance to confirm it I'll accept this answer. :-)

Comment: since windows 10 you'll get Linux behavior by default

Comment: ... so "It is not possible to get the Linux Terminal behavior" is incorrect

Comment: @Luu: Thanks for adding the info about Windows 10. But what do you mean with 'by default'? This suggests that there is an alternative behavior for pre-Windows 10 systems, which there isn't, so your comment is misleading. Also: Who is using Windows 10? (SCNR)

Comment: I use Windows 10 and it works **when copying output of commands** but not when copying statements from the command prompt. Example:   1) Type a command that spans multiple lines in command promp; 2) copy it - the unwanted NewLines will go to the clipboard as well).

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. You're literally a lifesaver, because I'll stop to lose all that time of my life editing out stupid newlines. It would be great to find some registry value to make this the default and _Shift_ the broken-line one. Or a way to hack `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to open the context menu of the console window's title bar, go to Properties and make the screen buffer's width large enough that things don't wrap. (9999 appears to be the maximum value.)

If you're having to do this a lot, you can change the option in Defaults instead of Properties.

Of course, this method breaks down if the lines are longer than 9999 characters.

Comment: Nice idea, too! Less obscure to use, but less visibility.

Comment: @Abraxas I've rewritten the answer in much more detail.

Answer (score 1):

To enable this for Windows 10:

With either a "cmd" or "Windows Powershell" window, navigate to properties (click icon in upper left) and select the option "Enable line wrapping selection".

My Powershell prompt did *not* have this enabled, enabling it did the trick for me.

Comment: I cannot find this option in Windows Terminal 1.8.1444.0 - do you know if there's a json setting?

Answer (score -2):

Just copy the code into notepad then in the menu bar,click `Format` then click `Word Wrap`

Answer (score -4):

Use the SET and then combine the parts in the expression. Additionally you can do for such purposes batch file or macro.

```
@set WAIKTools=%ProgramFiles%\WAIK\Tools\amd64
@set LabelCD=GRTMPVOL_RU

@IF "%time:~0,1%" GTR "0" SET current=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%@%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%
@IF "%time:~0,1%" LSS "0" SET current=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%@0%TIME:~1,1%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%

"%WAIKTools%\oscdimg.exe" -h -m -n -l%LabelCD% -b"%cd%\boot\w32sp3.bif" "BUILD-%current%" "BUILD-%current%-ISO\%LabelCD%.ISO"
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. Where is the copy part? Where is the Windows terminal part?